# i want to get incoming call number but number is empty

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I want to get an incoming number whenever anyone is going to be called but getting empty even after use `PhoneStateListener and BroadCastReceiver`.

First, clear my doubt that which one is the best to approach and why we use both `PhoneStateListener and BroadCastReceiver`.

> **Manifest File.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mytraining.com.callrecord">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".PhoneReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

> **MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

> **BroadcastReceiver.java**

```
    public class PhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
   private static String number = null;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.d(TAG, intent.getAction() + ", EXTRA_STATE: " + state);
        // on ringing get incoming number
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.d(TAG, "EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER: " + number);

        }
    }

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
        number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.d(TAG, intent.getAction() + ", EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER: " + number);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea about which approach is best, but this worked for me and may become helpful to you -

```
package com.incipientinfo.contactdetaildemo;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import java.util.Date;

public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
            {
                savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
            }
            else
            {
                String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                int state = 0;
                if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
                {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                }
                else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
                {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                }
                else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                }

                onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}

    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state)
        {

            return;
        }
        switch (state)
        {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if (isIncoming)
                {
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context,savedNumber,callStartTime,new Date());
                }

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if(isIncoming)
                {
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: On which device you are testing this. Did you gave Telephone permission to the devices above marshmallow?

Comment: I'm Testing On Android Pineapple 9.0